# Как корректно завершить программу на python

Tags: python

Знаю команду exit(),но в таком случае программа просто завершается и закрывается.Мне нужно что-бы после завершения программа просто прекратила дальнейшее выполнение цикла и остановилась не закрывая окно.
Вот пример

```
if hp1<1 or hp2<1:Death=100
if Death==100: print("____ТЕХНИКА УНИЧТОЖЕНА_____")
if Death==100:exit()
```

Comment: input() ; break

Comment: _"остановилась не закрывая окно"_, — а что потом? Вы можете заставить программу спать в цикле: `while True: time.sleep(1)`... Но зачем?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `break` и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Да, только break не функция, а оператор.

Comment: Да,точно.Сейчас поправлю.